# Cannot convert Varchar to DateTime - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Source Data that I am working with, this is all in one column called body. This data unfortunately cannot be changed. The data is coming in via an email from outside our Network it then goes into Email2DB. Email2DB is an application that puts the email data into a table.

This is not how data is usually stored in our tables, this is a temporary thing in place to log issues from user pc's whilst off the network so that number of issues can be tracked.

Body

```
21/05/2020| 16:01| Pathe 2.0 Delay| Pathe| LRW10| terence
```

For reporting purposes I am splitting the data into individual columns.

I need to get the separate date and time to be in one column as DateTime Format.
For example:  `2020-05-21 16:01`

I am trying to enter the data into the following temp table, but for the life of me I cannot get the date and time to convert to DateTime.

```
DECLARE @QuickData TABLE (TicketDate datetime, Issue varchar(50), Category varchar(50), ComputerName varchar(30), UserName varchar(50));
```

If I change the temp table TicketDate to be TicketDate varchar(25) the data goes in fine. However end goal is to be able to pass in a @DateFrom and @DateTo and be able to do a where TicketDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo and I cannot do this unless TicketDate is datetime format.

What I can't understand is even if I insert the data into a the temp table with Ticket as Varchar, the result looks like the below

[Result if insert TicketDate as Varchar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p8tq.png)

One the data is in the temp table I have tried running a select statement using cast as datetime and cast  as datetime2 and also have tried convert to datetime, but nothing works I always get the same error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I will add one of the attempts I have tried below if anyone can work it out I will be so grateful.

Please know I have googled endless ideas and tried multi formats for the date time.

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DateTime = '2020-05-21 08:00:00'
DECLARE @dateTo DateTime = '2020-05-25 17:30:00'


    DECLARE @QuickData TABLE (TicketDate varchar(25), Issue varchar(50), Category varchar(50), ComputerName varchar(30), UserName varchar(50));

        
    INSERT INTO @QuickData  
        SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), (TRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23))  + dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|') + ':00'),120),
    dbo.f_SplitString(body,3,'|') as 'Issue', dbo.f_SplitString(body,4,'|') as 'Category',
    dbo.f_SplitString(body,5,'|') as 'PCName', dbo.f_SplitString(body,6,'|') as 'User' FROM t_Quick;

    
    SELECT convert(datetime,TicketDate) as 'TicketDate' , Issue, Category, ComputerName, UserName 
    FROM @QuickData
    WHERE TicketDate between @dateFrom and @dateTo
    ORDER BY TicketDate DESC;
```

The Split String Function used is below.

```
USE [Central]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[f_SplitString]    Script Date: 26/06/2020 00:07:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_SplitString]
(
  @multiwordstring VARCHAR(255),
  @wordnumber      integer,
  @delimiter char(1)
)
returns VARCHAR(255)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @remainingstring VARCHAR(255)
      SET @remainingstring=@multiwordstring

      DECLARE @numberofwords NUMERIC
      SET @numberofwords=(LEN(@remainingstring) - LEN(REPLACE(@remainingstring, @delimiter, '')) + 1)

      DECLARE @word VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE @parsedwords TABLE
      (
         line NUMERIC IDENTITY(1, 1),
         word VARCHAR(255)
      )

      WHILE @numberofwords > 1
        BEGIN
            SET @word=LEFT(@remainingstring, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @remainingstring) - 1)

            INSERT INTO @parsedwords(word)
            SELECT @word

            SET @remainingstring= REPLACE(@remainingstring, @word + @delimiter, '')
            SET @numberofwords=(LEN(@remainingstring) - LEN(REPLACE(@remainingstring, @delimiter, '')) + 1)

            IF @numberofwords = 1
              BREAK

            ELSE
              CONTINUE
        END

      IF @numberofwords = 1
        SELECT @word = @remainingstring
      INSERT INTO @parsedwords(word)
      SELECT @word

      RETURN
        (SELECT RTrim(LTrim(word))
         FROM   @parsedwords
         WHERE  line = @wordnumber)

  END
```

Comment: So this `21/05/2020| 16:01| Pathe 2.0 Delay| Pathe| LRW10| terence` is _one column_? I think you need to push back and get data into your database in a better, more normalized format. Right now it's not a database, it's a text file.

Comment: Have you actually tried de-constructing your query into individual blocks to see where it is failing? In my simple testing (I don't have your implementation of `f_SplitString` function) it works. Run this: `SELECT CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23)), CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23))  + dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|')`. If it fails keep deleting code blocks from the end until you find out where the problem actually is.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The data is coming in via an email from an external source not in our Network it then goes through Email2DB. This application puts it into the table but cannot separate it into different columns, hence why I am stuck with such bad data to work with.

Comment: [This 20-year old thing](http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-addins/email2db.html) can't do anything except dump the entire set of data into a single column? Maybe it's time to look into different software.

Comment: Based on the fact that you have spaces in your text string, I suspect that your string split function is doing trimming and thus you loose a space between date and hour components, hence I have asked you to de-construct your query to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I have finally figured out the problem though. When converting the time there is a 'not ordinary' space the space cannot be removed by the TRIM and so the solution was using substring and it works great.

```
    DECLARE @QuickData TABLE (TicketDate datetime, Issue varchar(50), Category varchar(50), ComputerName varchar(30), UserName varchar(50));


    INSERT INTO @QuickData  
        SELECT convert(datetime, try_CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), (TRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23))  + ' ' + substring(dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|'),2,5) + ':00'),120)), 
    dbo.f_SplitString(body,3,'|') as 'Issue', dbo.f_SplitString(body,4,'|') as 'Category',
    dbo.f_SplitString(body,5,'|') as 'PCName', dbo.f_SplitString(body,6,'|') as 'User' FROM t_Quick;


    Select * from @QuickData
    where TicketDate between @dateFrom and @dateTo
    order by 1 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to parse the string via XML  (JSON is another option if 2016)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[body] varchar(150))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'21/05/2020| 16:01| Pathe 2.0 Delay| Pathe| LRW10| terence')
 

Select A.ID
      ,DateCol  = try_convert(datetime,Pos1+' '+Pos2,103)
      ,Issue    = Pos3
      ,Category = Pos4
      ,PCName   = Pos5
      ,[User]   = Pos6
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace([body],'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a table-valued function like this, which returns a string split in order:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnOrderedStringSplit
(
    @List       varchar(4000),
    @Delimiter  char(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT Element = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Number]),
               [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
                 CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, [Number]
                 ) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT TOP (4000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
            FROM sys.all_columns) AS x ([Number])
        WHERE SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, [Number], 1) = @Delimiter
          AND Number <= LEN(@List)
    );
```

Then you can pivot that to extract specific elements:

```
-- INSERT @QuickData(TicketDate, Issue, Category, ComputerName, UserName)
SELECT TicketDate = TRY_CONVERT(datetime, [1] + ' ' + [2], 103),
       Issue      = [3],
       Category   = [4],
       PCName     = [5],
       UserName   = [6]
  FROM dbo.t_QuickData AS t 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnOrderedStringSplit(t.body, '|') AS f
  PIVOT (MAX([Value]) FOR Element IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) AS p;
```

Comment: Better datetime with the string concat

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Your string splitting function trims strings, hence you are loosing the space between date and time components.

Change your code

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), (TRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23))
    + dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|') + ':00'),120),
```

to

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), (TRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23))
   + ' ' + dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|') + ':00'),120),
```

Note the blank space before `dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|')`

### "Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish, and You Feed Him for a Lifetime"

You can easily debug this yourself by deconstructing your query as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105) FROM t_Quick
SELECT CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23)) FROM t_Quick
SELECT CONVERT(date, dbo.f_SplitString(body,1,'|'), 105), 23))  + dbo.f_SplitString(body,2,'|') FROM t_Quick
```

You can look at the output at each stage to see where the problem lays.